# Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException on my NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been trying to add a object in my array. Here's what I've done so far:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableMenuArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dictionary[MJFeedDataKey]];
[mutableMenuArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
[mutableMenuArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];

NSMutableArray *menuArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[menuArray addObjectsFromArray:mutableMenuArray];
[menuArray addObject:@"Check"];

MJMenuEntities *menus = [MJMenuEntities sharedInstance];
[menus setWithArray:menuArray];
self.modelArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:menus.menuItems];
```

But once I've set the `menus` to `menuArray` it comes up with an error:

> "Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException on my NSArray".

But if the `menus` is set to `mutableMenuArray` there is no error.

Comment: Sounds like an issue within the setWithArray method.  The only difference b/n your arrays is @"Check", so maybe setWithArray doesn't like that string?  Does it work when you comment out the line that adds that string?

Comment: You don't need `menuArray` either. You could just do `[mutableMenuArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];  [mutableMenuArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];  [mutableMenuArray addObject:@"Check"];`  and give `menus` that array. Anyway, if you're getting an exception, it's a problem with `setWithArray` it probably modifies the array.

Comment: @conarch Yes, it is working when I comment out that line

Comment: @Brandon When i do that, same error occurs. Maybe because mutableMenuArray is not allocated or whatnot

Comment: What is the actual exception message?  Which line of code does it occur on?

Comment: Without extra info, I'm thinking that MJMenuEntities is expecting menuArray to have objects of a certain type, and that type is NOT NSString.  Based on your naming convention, I suspect NSData or JSON arrays/dictionaries.

Comment: @conarch It is expecting a NSDictionary, thanks. Now, how can I add a NSDictionary into my array?

Comment: @drbj if you want to add dictionary in array than use  mutableMenuArray=[dictionaryname objectforkey:@"objectname"];

Answer (score 0):

NSArray is immutable. It seems like you modify the first parameter of the method:- setWithArray.

Can you paste the details of the method:- setWithArray.